# Date format renders different result in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-format, date-formatting

I am trying to render the date but the result is different in firefox and IE. The output is:

July 21, 2015 at 3:13 PM -- Firefox

Tuesday, July 21, 2015 at 3:13:10 PM -- IE

How Do I make IE not show the day and seconds?

My code is (Let's say dateVal is 1440671523862):

```
    function csDateFormatProvider(evalFilter) {
    return function (dateVal, type, message) {
        var options = {
                month : "long",
                day : "numeric",
                year : "numeric"
            },
            localDate = new Date(),
            adjustedDataDate = new Date(dateVal),
            localeTime = adjustedDataDate.toLocaleTimeString(csConfig.LOCALE, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'}),
            localeDate = adjustedDataDate.toLocaleDateString(csConfig.LOCALE, options);

        if (type === "date") {
            return adjustedDataDate.toLocaleDateString(csConfig.LOCALE, options);
        } else if (type === "date-time") {
            if (localDate.getFullYear() === adjustedDataDate.getFullYear() &&
                    localDate.getMonth() === adjustedDataDate.getMonth()) {
            if(localDate.getDate() === adjustedDataDate.getDate()) {
                    return app.evaluate(message, messages.TODAY, localeTime);
                } else if (localDate.getDate() === (adjustedDataDate.getDate() + 1)) {
                    return app.evaluate(message, messages.YESTERDAY, localeTime);
                }
            }
            return app.evaluate(message, localeDate, localeTime);
        } else {
            return app.evaluate(message, localeDate, localeTime);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What language are you programming in?  Javascript?  Edit your question to include the language tag.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf This is Javascript, and made the edit on the question as well.